# String is being truncated when passed in request using jquery ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

i'm trying to pass a string in the request back to the jsp servlet post method but the string is being truncated.
the string is 40K+ in length

the post call looks like: `$.post("assignedStructure", "data=" + str);`

in the post method, i can get the data from the request param, but the string is being truncated.

when submitting the form (not through JS calls) the same string is not truncated and is complete. i do not want to post the entire page, as i just need to get the data onto the server side to process and save changes (the string is basically a json string containing information that needs saved).

getting the data in the post method looks like:

```
    if(request.getParameter("data") != "" && request.getParameter("data") != null"){            
        //get the orgs from the request param
        ArrayList<Organization> orgs = Util.CreateDataArray(request                     .getParameter("data"));
    //rest of method.......
    }

    public static ArrayList<Organization> CreateDataArray(String jsonString) {
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

            JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(jsonString);
//rest of method........
```

is there a max length of string for an ajax post or a jquery ajax post?

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're not encoding the `str` right. Like maybe there's a `&` in it or something.

Also, as a sidenote, `str == ""` is not the proper way to compare strings in Java.  Should be `"".equals(str)` or `str.equals("")`; using `==` on strings in Java compares memory locations (i.e. pointer equivalence) not contents.  You do use `str == null`, however, since `null` is a pointer.

I originally thought your Ajax syntax was wrong, and that it should be:

```
$.post( "assignedStructure", { data: str } );
```

See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). In the `data` section of the function they always use JSON object in the examples, not a string:  So `{ data: str }` not `"data=" + str`.  But as Athony points out in the comments it does say you can do it either way. For me, though it seems strange to see the `var=val` syntax with POST, since it looks like confusing GET with POST at first sight.

Comment: You mean the docs that say `data` can be either PlainObject or String? Passing it as an object probably handles the need to encode it for you, though; I've never tested it.